# How to pass a command funcion over an event one on discordpy?

Tags: discord.py

I made a bot that changes nicknames of members when they type !nick + their nickname and id of a game. The problem is, some people are unaware of how to use the commands to do that, so they get stuck in my registrarion text-chat. Here is the code:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    channel = message.channel
    if message.content.startswith('!nick'):
        pass
    else:
        await channel.send("Algo deu errado aqui. Não esqueça de escrever !nick antes de digitar seu nome e ID do servidor.")

@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def nick(ctx, nickname, sobrenick, ident=''):
    autor = ctx.message.author
    channel = client.get_channel(channel_id)
    if ctx.message.content.startswith('!nick'):
        if ident == '':
            await autor.edit(nick=nickname + "  |  " + sobrenick)
            await ctx.send(f'Seu nick foi alterado para: {nickname}  |  {sobrenick}, se confirma digite !entrar pra continuar, se não redigite o nick')
        else:
            await autor.edit(nick=nickname + "  " + sobrenick + "  |  " + ident)
            await ctx.send(f'Seu nick foi alterado para: {nickname} {sobrenick}  |  {ident}, se confirma digite !entrar pra continuar, se não redigite o nick')
```

As you guys can see, to solve that I've tried to make an event before the command that triggers whenever a person types something that doesnt start with '!nick', and then made the bot sent a message explaining that they need to use !nick before their actual info to make it work.

I don't know if its because of the 'pass' after the if, or if its because event classes rules above command ones, but I'm a little bit new to python and what I was expecting with that was to the bot just send a message on the channel telling the member to use the right command until he does it right.

But the else condition on the event class just doesnt work. I've tried to include the same else condition on the command class too, following the "if ctx.message.content.startswith('!nick'):", and it doesnt work also...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you override the default `on_message` event, you need to add [client.process_commands](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=process_commands#discord.ext.commands.Bot.process_commands) to allow the bot to process the registered commands.

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    ...
    await client.process_commands(message)
```

Or you can use [client.listen](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=listen#discord.ext.commands.Bot.listen) instead of `client.event`

```py
@client.listen("on_message")
async def my_on_message(message):
    ...
```

[Here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#why-does-on-message-make-my-commands-stop-working) is the FAQ from discord.py about this issue.

Comment: thank you! I managed to achieve what I wanted after working a bit with the process_comands